# How to add add TextView below ListView in a DrawerLayout so that it fills width and height properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-linearlayout

I am tasked with adding a TextView below ListView in a DrawerLayout. The TextView must stay at the bottom. I've achieved this partially (see "Request Removal" item in pic), but there are some aspects that I cannot get right.  The Drawer has worked fine for a while btw.  I'm just trying to modify what's there without changing too much.

1. As you can see the TextView is not wide enough or tall enough, allowing the blue from the background to show through.
2. The only way I could even get the TextView to show at bottom was by making the layout_height of the ListView to be 500dp.  If layout_height stays match_parent, the new TextView won't even appear. Hardcoding a dp value here seems to be wrong.  I hardcoded a layout_height for the TextView hoping it would "push up" against the ListView so that the TextView could appear, but no workie.

The layout is below too.

How do I properly modify my layout so that the TextView with "Request Removal" appear at bottom without the ugliness?

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.allinlearning.assist_android.HomeScreenActivityFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_screen"
    />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/ail_background_gradient_horiz"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:layout_width="280dp"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".08"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvDrawerBlankSpace"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size18"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Options"
        android:id="@+id/tvDrawerTitle"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size20"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDrawerItems"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="@color/LightGrey"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".11"
        android:text="Request Removal"
        android:id="@+id/tvRequestRemoval"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size16"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once -I have made few changes with UI may its help you.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->

<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.allinlearning.assist_android.HomeScreenActivityFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_screen"
    />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/purple_500">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDrawerBlankSpace"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDrawerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:text="Options"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDrawerBlankSpace" />
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDrawerItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/header_divider"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDrawerTitle"
            tools:listitem="@layout/activity_main" />
    
        <View
            android:id="@+id/header_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRequestRemoval"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Request Removal"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

create XML in drawable/rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><shape>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
            android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: I cannot get that to build.  The problems begin with androidx.constraintlayout.  This app doesn't use androidx, and I need to avoid changing things as much as possible.  I don't need this constraintlayout, tho.  This is a pretty simple layout and Linear should be adequate. See my pic?  I'm very close already.

Comment: I finally got it to build, but it doesn't work. Drawer is expanded over the whole screen.  Thank you, but if you can modify the layout in the question to tweak the height and width of that TextView it would be very helpful.

Comment: Then try that Framelayout with textview its also useful to add in your Linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to remove these two lines from the layout of the problematic TextView.  Duh.

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
```